# Facebook login connect status

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using fb login connect in my demo site :
I used this code:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      try{
        FB.init({
            apiKey: '<MY APP KEY>',
            channelUrl : 'www.google.com'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            loginHandler(); 
        });
      }catch(error){}
  };  
    function loginHandler(success,fail)
    {

        try{
            if(success){
                alert('i am if');
                FB.api('/me', function(response,fail) {
                    alert("first name == " + response.first_name + "\n ln === " + response.last_name);
                });
            }
        }catch(error){}
    }

    $('#login').bind('click', function(response) {
        try{
            FB.login(loginHandler, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
        }catch(error){}
    });

    $('#logout').bind('click', function() {
        try{
            FB.logout(function(response){});
        }catch(error){}
      });
```

Now my problem is that **alert('i am if');** is showing every time whether I passed **correct credentials** to *facebook* or not and **alert("first name == " + response.first_name + "\n ln === " + response.last_name);** shows **undefined** when user passes **wrong credentials** and shows correct info when user comes back passing **correct info**.

one possible option is to check like `if(response.first_name!=undefined){blah blah....}` but is it correct method of checking the authentication?

Please shed some light....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//for login
    $("#login").bind("click", function(e) {     
        var fbScope = "email,user_likes";
        FB.login(function(response) {          
           if(response.status == "connected"){
               console.log("Logged in");
           }
        },{scope: fbScope});
    });
    //for checking logged in status
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if (response.authResponse) {    
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('I m still loggedin');
            });         
        }
    });
    //for logout
    $("#logout").live("click", function(e) {        
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){           
            if(response.status == "connected"){
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                    console.log("I m logged out now");                  
                });
           } else {
                console.log("Not Logged logged in");
           }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) and `FB.api` doesn't provide you success/failure reporting just like you trying to implement it. There is no second argument for callbacks...

`FB.login` callback get one and only argument:

> response from [`FB.getLoginStatus`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/), [`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) or [`FB.logout`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout). This response object contains:
>
> **status**
> The status of the User. One of connected, not_authorized or unknown.
> **authResponse**
> The authResponse object.

`FB.api` callback get one and only arguments which is response from Graph API usually (but not always) containing `data` property, object fields, boolean false or `error` object (with `message`, `type` and `code` properties)

---

You can modify your `loginHandler` by correction of response callbacks to take care of right arguments:

```
function loginHandler(loginResponse){
  try{
    if(loginResponse.authResponse){
      alert('i am if');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert("first name == " + response.first_name +
              "\n ln === " + response.last_name);
      });
    }
  }catch(error){}
}
```

Comment: @ankur20us, I'll provide some details in a minute ;)